# Does mono.cache works for Webclient response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I'm trying to cache an authentication token response which is returned by a webclient call.

```
public Mono<Token> getToken() {
  return webclient.post().retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Token.class)
        .cache(this::getTokenLiveDuration, t -> Duration.ZERO, () -> Duration.ZERO).log();
}

public Mono<MyResponse> execute() {
  return getToken().flatMap(token -> {
        webclient.post().header("Auth", token.getValue())
                 .retrieve()
                 .bodyToMono(MyResponse.class)
        }
}
```

But if I run `execute()` two time in a same instance, they have different tokens, which means the cache did not work.

What's the correct way of using `.cache` or the correct way to cache webclient response?

Answer (score 1):

That's because each time `getToken` is called a new `Mono` is created with its own cache.

One way to make caching effective is creating a field for the cached token `Mono` and use that `Mono` in the execute method.

Comment: Are you saying I have to initialize a mono field with webclient?

Comment: Yes, for example in constructor.